# Issue with scanf(...) and fgets(...)

Tags: c

I'm doing the [alternating characters problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/alternating-characters).

**Problem:**

> Shashank likes strings in which consecutive characters are different.
>   For example, he likes ABABA, while he doesn't like ABAA. Given a
>   string containing characters A and B only, he wants to change it into
>   a string he likes. To do this, he is allowed to delete the characters
>   in the string.
>
> Your task is to find the minimum number of required deletions.
>
> Input Format The first line contains an integer T i.e. the number of
>   test cases. Next T lines contain a string each.
>
> Output Format Print minimum number of required steps for each test
>   case.
>
> Constraints
>
> 1≤T≤10 1≤ length of String ≤105

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int t,i,j;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    char line[100000];

    for(i=0; i < t; i++){
        //get string from user
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        //loop line and greedily solve this
        int deletions = 0;
        if(strlen > 0){
            char currentChar = line[0];
            for(j=1; j < strlen(line); j++){
                if(currentChar == line[j]){
                    deletions++;
                }else{
                    currentChar = line[j];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", deletions);
        //empty string
        memset(line,0,strlen(line));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
5
AAAA
BBBBB
ABABABAB
BABABA
AAABBB
```

**My output:**

```
0
3
4
0
0
```

**Expected Output:**

```
3
4
0
0
4
```

I'm not a C expert, so I'm sorry if this an obvious question.  It seems my `fgets` catches an empty line when it shouldn't.  My guess was it was related to `scanf`.  However, I'm not sure why and I'm not sure how to fix it?

Comment: `if(strlen > 0)` --> `if(strlen(line) > 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new line character in your file right after the '5' that you ignore, should be:

```
scanf("%d\n", &t);
```

That of course assuming you have a unix-file (e.g. only `\n` as new line)

Comment: Would work on Windows as well as stdin is opened in text-mode.

Comment: It ***was*** something obvious ha. Will mark correct as soon as it will let me.

Comment: And would work on windows as `\n` matches every whitespace character (`"%d "` and `"%d\n"` are equivalent format strings).

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens only if you haven't swallow the '\n' in the first line of the input data. You could use a simple `getchar()` to catch that character:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int t,i,j;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    char line[100000];

    getchar();   /// HERE!!!!!
    for(i=0; i < t; i++){
        //get string from user
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        //loop line and greedily solve this
        int deletions = 0;
        if(strlen > 0){
            char currentChar = line[0];
            for(j=1; j < strlen(line); j++){
                if(currentChar == line[j]){
                    deletions++;
                }else{
                    currentChar = line[j];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", deletions);
        //empty string
        memset(line,0,strlen(line));
    }

    return 0;
}
```